# Should I pay attention in calculus proofs

Tags: calculus, soft-question, education

I'm learning multivariable calculus now, and when I look at the proof of the theorems on youtube, I always hear these sentences 'This proof is not rigorous enough, 'I'm being here a bit handwavy'.

For example, look at the proof of the arc length of a function: calculus textbook use Pythagoras equation like this $$ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$$ and then $$ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=\sqrt{1+\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}}dx$$

integrating $$S=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$$ and there is a similar method for finding the arclength of a vector valued function.

Now, since I'm gonna learn real analysis later, should I pay attention to the proofs of calculus, I think that this is just a waste of time since the proofs aren't rigorous enough?

Comment: When people say "this is not a rigorous proof" or "I'm being handwavey" they aren't saying that rigorous proofs don't exist, only that for their purposes they're choosing to not present a completely rigorous proof. This is usually done because proofs will often contain technical details that take up too much time to be presented in full in a lesson, and also give the students an opportunity to figure out the details themselves. You should definitely pay attention to the proofs, and then attempt to fill in the gaps yourself.

Comment: A non-rigorous proof can still be immensely useful in retaining concepts, and often the non-rigorous version of the proof can be extended to a formal proof by extending the language and adding some more formal argumentation. The reason people don't always present the full, formal proof is that the added language and argumentation are often a little bit much when the purpose is to motivate a concept rather than formally prove it (This is especially true when they say they're "being handwavey," it's not that their argument is invalid, it's just that they're not going through in full detail)

Comment: I can't understand what you want to show with your arc length example.

Comment: Is that a completely rigorous proof? @YvesDaoust

Comment: In fact, I have no idea how this could be made fully rigorous without advanced geometry concepts, to be put in correspondence with calculus.